# Вывод из БД в цикле только одной записи с одинаковым полем

Tags: php, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Более точно не могу описать роблему в заголовке, поэтому постараюсь объяснить здесь. Вообщем, в БД есть таблица с товарами, допустим режущие диски, в которых есть одинаковые диски, но которые отличаютя только диаметром и ценой а все другие поля одинаковые. Мне нужно вывести по в цикле по одному диску с одинаковым названием. Т.е. допустим есть:<br>
DIAM / 120 мм / 1200 р<br>
DIAM / 110 mm / 1100 p<br>
DIAM / 100 mm / 1000p<br>
ALMAZ / 90 mm / 1350p<br>
ALMAZ / 110 mm / 1500 p<br>
Вот так они выглядят в таблице. Мне нужно вывести в цикле по одному диску с одинаковым названием. Подскажите, как это делается. Возможно уже есть готовое решение, но в связи с тем, что не могу достаточно корректно описать проблему не могу найти в поиске.
 Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в таблице все параметры диска в разных столбцах(disk_name - название, disk_size - диаметр, disk_price - цена), то примерно так:

```
$q = 'select * from items group by disk_name';
$res = mysql_query($q);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
   print $row['disk_name'].' '.$row['disk_size'].' '.$row['disk_price'];
}
```

тоесть нужно задать группировку по имени диска (group by disk_name).
Может получится, что 1м диском будет не самый дорогой. Тогда нужно добавить сортировку по нужному параметру в строку:

```
$q = 'select * from items group by disk_name ORDER BY disk_price desc';
```

Выведет все названия дисков, по одному диску каждого имени, и при этом самые дорогие.
Доки по [SQL](http://sql.itsoft.ru/select/)

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось